# Getting Exception from javadoc

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube, javadoc

Currently I am working with `SonarQube` rules migration and now I'm stuck with this parameter:

```
allowThrowsTagsForSubclasses - whether to allow documented exceptions that are subclass of one of declared exception.
```

Currently for various properties I am getting `javadoc` content as `String` and then extracting what I need. Using same methods I'm only able to get exception name as a `String`. But in this case `String` is not what I'm looking for. I need to get documented exception not as `String` and then receive it's parent to check if it is subclass of declared exception.

Only thought I have about solving this (using `Strings`) is to create whole bunch of static `arrayLists` with each exception `subclasses`. But there is a lot of them and some of them are going even deeper than 2 times.

Maybe there is a way to extract Exception as object with capability to find its parent?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what exactly you are asking. I think we need a different level of details here...

Comment: added more detailed explanation

Comment: It isn't clear to me how your "environment" looks like. Are you saying you have to implement a certain rule yourself? And that you only have javadoc output at hand?  (but no complete "class path" will classes used)?

Comment: yes, I need to write a rule where one of many checks is this one. Rule will check methods. And I need to find a way how to check if documented exceptions can be subclasses of declared exception. I can use other methods (which does not require to include additional dependencies).

Comment: What SonarQube version and Plugins do you use?

Comment: Currently company is using 6.7.2 version. Also bunch of plugins. But my task is to migrate custom company rules (created using PMD and checkstyle rules templates) to pure sonar (so it will work with sonarlint ar would not need for other plugins than SonarJava (squid rules also uses only this plugin))